# checkbox now visible if put after `nav` element

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In the following code, I do not see the `checkbox` if I put it after `nav`. Why?

```
<body>
<!-- If I remove nav completely, I see the checkbox, else I do not -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </nav>

    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
    <label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label> 


    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: try creating a snippet / working example 
 read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just a wild guess but you have a class of "fixed-top" on that element. Would lead me to believe that class uses `position: fixed;` which would take that element out of your normal document flow and it would appear on top of your normal items including your checkbox.

Comment: yeah @RobertWade could be right here , try adding margin-top to you check box 5 px more than the height of navigation , just to check if it is hiding behind the navigation ?